# camera slips trough the terrain limit (the given edges of the terrain) every time i rotate the camera - how can i fix that?

Tags: camera, rotation, limit, terrain

I already tried to clamp it with mathf or hardocding it, but it didnt help either, it just slips trough, every time I rotate the camera on the edge of the map (min/max hsp - min/max vsp) the given edges of the terrain.

I'm out of ideas and searched days for a similar problem in hope to see my mistake and now I'm here. Hopefully someone can help me and show me the mistake I made. I want to learn so badly. you can see the code I used here:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    float speed = 1f;
    float zoomSpeed = 10f;
    float rotateSpeed = 50f;

    float maxHeight = 200f;
    float minHeight = 20f;

    float minHsp = 10f;
    float maxHsp = 750f;
    float minVsp = 10f;
    float maxVsp = 750f;

    Vector2 p1;
    Vector2 p2;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            speed = 1f;
            zoomSpeed = 2000f;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 0.5f;
            zoomSpeed = 1550f;
        }
        float hsp = transform.position.y * speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
        float vsp = transform.position.y * speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
        float scrollSP = Mathf.Log(transform.position.y) * -zoomSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * Time.deltaTime;

        if ((transform.position.y >= maxHeight) && (scrollSP > 0))
        {
            scrollSP = 0;
        }
        else if ((transform.position.y <= minHeight) && (scrollSP <0))
        {
            scrollSP = 0;
        }

        if((transform.position.y + scrollSP) > maxHeight)
        {
            scrollSP = maxHeight - transform.position.y;
        }
        else if((transform.position.y + scrollSP) < minHeight)
        {
            scrollSP = minHeight - transform.position.y;
        }

        if ((transform.position.x >= maxHsp) && (hsp > 0))
        {
            hsp = 0;
        }
        else if ((transform.position.x <= minHsp) && (hsp < 0))
        {
            hsp = 0;
        }

        if ((transform.position.x + hsp) > maxHsp)
        {
            hsp = maxHsp - transform.position.x;
        }
        else if ((transform.position.x + hsp) < minHsp)
        {
            hsp = minHsp - transform.position.x;
        }

        if ((transform.position.z >= maxVsp) && (vsp > 0))
        {
            vsp = 0;
        }
        else if ((transform.position.z <= minVsp) && (vsp < 0))
        {
            vsp = 0;
        }

        if ((transform.position.z + vsp) > maxVsp)
        {
            vsp = maxVsp - transform.position.z;
        }
        else if ((transform.position.z + vsp) < minVsp)
        {
            vsp = minVsp - transform.position.z;
        }

        Vector3 verticalMove = new Vector3(0,scrollSP,0);
        Vector3 lateralMove = hsp * transform.right;
        Vector3 forwardMove = transform.forward;
        forwardMove.y = 0;
        forwardMove.Normalize();
        forwardMove *= vsp;
        
        Vector3 move = verticalMove + lateralMove + forwardMove;

        transform.position += move;

        getCameraRotation();

    }
    void getCameraRotation()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        {
            p1 = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(2))
        {
            p2 = Input.mousePosition;

            float dx = (p2 - p1).x * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            float dy = (p2 - p1).y * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,dx,0));
            transform.GetChild(0).transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(-dy,0,0));

            p1 = p2;
        }
    }
}
```